# 3D clustering using survey data

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis

I have data obtained from a survey of respondents and I would like to perform a 3D clustering of the individuals who have answered the survey based on 3 of the questions they have answered:

- Are you satisfied with product x? The range of answers is: strongly agree, agree, neutral, not satisfied, not satisfied at all.
- Would you buy product x again? the range of answers is: strongly agree, agree, neutral, do not agree, do not agree, do not agree at all.
- How much would you recommend product x to your family, friends... (range from 0 to 10)?

The thing is that I am not sure how to start, do you think I should first convert the answers of the first two questions to numbers (for example: strongly agree : 1)? I also have doubts about the libraries that allow me to do this.

The result I would like to get would be something like the example graphical representation you can see on the following page, rotated and showing the clusters found: https://projector.tensorflow.org/

Any examples would be welcome.

Comment: You are looking to use very advanced tools on very basic data. I would first perform a simple k-means or a hierarchical cluster - it's very likely that it would be good enough. Although Likert scales are ordinal in nature, it is common to treat the data as metric.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You have 5 x 5 x 10 = 250 possible locations for data in your 3d space. If you will probably have many cases that overlap if you have very many cases. Your data will look nothing like the example you included which is based on continuous data.